# Inverse metric tensor as a map?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, vector-fields

I understand that the metric tensor is a natural map between vectors and 1-forms. For instance, this is shown below:

$g(v,.) $

That is a 1-form since eats a vector and gives you a real number. However, it's not clear to me how to pass from 1-form to a vector using the metric. Is there something as in the case of the start? For instance, I have to go from the 1 form.

$du=dt-dx$
to the vector:

$\nabla u = -\partial_{ t}-\partial_{x}$

The result is intuitive but the procedure it is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

In components the metric is given by $g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu\otimes dx^\nu$ which eats vectors whose component forms are $v^\mu\partial_\mu$. Since the metric is non-degenerate, it has an inverse $g^{-1}=g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\otimes\partial_\nu$ which satisfies $\delta^\mu_\nu=g^{\mu\lambda}g_{\lambda\nu}$. In this way $g$ defines a map from $TM$ to $T^*M$ as you say and $g^{-1}$ defines a map from $T^*M$ to $TM$ in the same way, and these maps are indeed inverses of each other.

These ideas are usually formalized in a coordinate-independent language by the so-called musical isomorphisms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see that $g(v,.)$ is a one form. But I don't see for instance that the inverse g(-1)(w, .) is in fact a vector.

Comment: @OMARMEDINABAUTISTA Note that $g^{-1}$ takes two 1-forms as arguments (vectors are linear maps to the reals on covectors). Hence $g^{-1}(w,\cdot)$ eats one more 1-form, making it a vector.

Comment: I thought that vectors eat functions and give a number.

Comment: @OMARMEDINABAUTISTA Vectors do both, but these things are distinct. Forms are the thing you integrate over, doesn't make them any less linear maps from vectors to reals. Simply observe that the covector space of the covector space is isomorphic to the original vector space.

Comment: @OMARMEDINABAUTISTA Thinking about it further, the action of vectors on functions you have in mind should really be viewed as a special case of the Lie derivative.

Answer (score 1):

You take the inverse matrix of $g_{ab}$ to be $g^{ab}$, which you can then treat as an operator that eats a pair of one forms and spits out reals.  Then, it should be pretty clear that mapping a vector to a one form and back to a vector is the identity operation, and that the inner product of two vectors is equal to the inner product of the two one-forms created from those vectors.

In the case of Minkowski, the operation is kind of confusing, because the Minkowski metric in $(t, x, y, z)$ coordinates is its own inverse.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to offer a short comment on Richard Myers' answer, which however contained to much math to fit into the comment section, therefore i'm adding it here as an Answer.

Let $p$ be a point in $M$, and $g$ a metric on $M$, and $\alpha$ is a one-form on $M$. One-forms are linear functionals on vectors, i.e. $\alpha_p : T_pM \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The space of linear functionals on a vector space is called the (algebraic) dual space and denoted by a star, i.e. one writes $\alpha \in (T_pM)^* = T^*_pM$. As was explained in another answer, a metric $g$ on $M$ allows to define an inverse metric $g^{-1}$ on $T^*M$. Then for each one form $\alpha$ we have that $g^{-1}_p(\alpha_p,\cdot)$ maps linear functionals at $p$ into the reals, or in other words, $g^{-1}_p(\alpha_p,\cdot) \in (T_pM)^{**}$.

We can now use that for any finite-dimensional vector space $V$ we have $V \cong V^{**}$ canonically. Indeed: let $\varphi \in V^*$, then for each $v\in V$ we get the evaluation map $x_v\in V^{**}$ given as
$$ x_v(\varphi) = \varphi(v) \ . $$
This gives an embedding $V \subset V^{**}$.

Using this backwards, we get a vector.